# Checkbox next to label

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to get my form's input to have a checkbox left to the label.

Here's an idea of what it looks like currently:

[image]

And how I'd like it to look like:

[image]

Here's the fiddle of the form, the components are added dynamically on window show.

http://jsfiddle.net/oa1oyenL/

I looked into `beforeLabelTpl` but I was not able to find example I understood that could do something like this and also because apparently, components created through `XTemplate` are not managed by the framework (events, component creation/desctruction, etc.)

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: where is the code , fiddle ??

Comment: @Sarath I doubt code would be useful as I am not having any bug with any code at the moment. Anyone that potentially has a clue about my question probably knows how to create such a form in ExtJS.

Comment: Use a hbox layout on the items where you want the checkbox.

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe a fiddle would be useful as this is within a fieldset.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli This within a fieldset, I edited my question.

Comment: Doesn't matter, just wrap those fields in a hbox layout.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli So every items of the fieldset should be a panel with an hbox layout, one item of the panel should be the checkbox and the other the field item component ? I just tried that and it seems to do the job.

Comment: You don't have to do all of them, only the ones that need a checkbox.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli That works great. Little tweaking to do as the style is a bit different from the one defined in the fieldset's defaults, but it works. If you propose it as answer, I'll mark it.